# react router showing the wrong component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Im new to React and Im creating a simple react app. I currently implement react-router. Im just want to ask what's the difference between this

```
<Route path="/projects/add" component={Addproject} />
```

to this

```
<Route path="/projects/:id" component={Projectitem} />
```

I cant seem to get it. When I click the link it says

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

and the AddProject Component wont show. It seems like its taking me to the ProjectItem Component despite me clicking the link to AddProject. Where did I go wrong?

Here is my router code.

```
<Router>
        <div>

          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top lead">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="navbar-brand pull-left">
                <ul className="navbar-nav">
                  <li className="active"><Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">Home Page</Link></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li className="nav-item active">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
                      <i className="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home
                      <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/projects">
                      <i className="fa fa-fw fa-briefcase"></i> Projects
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/page1/Jason">Page 1</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/page2">Page 2</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>

          <Switch>
            <Home>
              <Route exact path="/" component={User} />
              <Route exact path="/projects" component={Project} />
              <Route path="/projects/add" component={Addproject} />
              <Route path="/projects/:id" component={Projectitem} />
              <Route path="/page1/:name" component={Page1} />
              <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
            </Home>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
```

I've been reading and I read something about match. Can someone please teach me how to use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `exact path`?

Comment: Yes. Still the same result.

Comment: It seems that your error does not appeared in that file. Can you check the line and file where the error occurred ?

Comment: The error lies within here.

 `{this.state.projectItem.title}`

It says that title is null whenever I access the add project link. It seems to me that /projects/:id and /projects/add are the same path and project item component are the one getting rendered by the router.

Answer (score 1):

Its seems that I've got a little understanding how this router works. I've read that

```
/projects/add
```

and

`/projects/:id`

are the same path. A quick solution would be

```
/projects/list/:id
```

and

```
/projects/add
```

But I dont want to do it like this. I would like to learn a much better approach rather than customizing my links. Thanks to anyone who would answer. Sorry im such a noobie. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using your params in Projectitem component like this: `const { params } = this.props.match` then you could use your id var like this: `<p>Project ID:
 {params.id}</p>`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the ProjectItem component works well. Its the AddProject component thats not working. Its seems like the app is searching for the match.params in the AddProject component which clearly do not exist. Thanks for the time tho buddy.